# When did Warehouse 13 reference John Ringo’s novels?

Tags: warehouse-13, john-ringo

The [Acknowledgments](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781451637892B/9781451637892B___0.htm) of John Ringo’s new novel [Queen of Wands](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-1639-queen-of-wands.aspx) states:

> I’d like to thank the writers and producers [of *Warehouse 13*] for not only making a really good television show (words that are very hard for me to type as they’re so uncommon) but for **featuring my novels in one of the backgrounds**. [*clarification & emphasis added*]

To what does the phrase I’ve boldfaced refer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thaddeus is correct - in the episode "Emily Lake" (season 3, episode 11) at the 12:40 mark, there is a copy of *Eye of the Storm* on the book shelf in the background.

Comment: That episode is on Netflix, and I see it now, although you have to look close.  The best view seems to be around the end of minute 14 (Netflix doesn't show seconds).  Even then, it's not easy to read the title.

Answer (score 2):

I unfortunately cannot tell you the episode it appears in but the shout-out is for showing an episode featured a copy of John Ringo's **Eye of the Storm** in the background on a bookshelf. I am going through my Warehouse 13 collection to see if I can find a screenshot. Ringo repaid the nod with a cameo in Queen of Wands for Artie and Claudia bagging an artifact.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Warehouse 13 S03E11 1250 John Ringo Eye of the Storm]

It's in the Season 3 Episode 11 "Emily Lake" of Warehouse 13, at 12:50. John Ringo's Eye of the Storm in on the top shelf on the right.